# What is the status of the request.referer method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just started working on a rails legacy app (2.3.5) and it has some code:

@req = request.referer

I checked some docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/referer and it says that the last stable version for this was 2.2.1.  Even though it says the same for the 'referrer' method.. I debugged it the request object says that it has both of these methods available to it.

Why do these methods work for me.. when the docs say they've been deprecated?

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean removed. It just means that they're no longer considered good practice, probably don't work as intended, and might be removed in the future, so you should stop using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Rails [moved to Rack in version 2.3.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#rack-integration) it started depending on Rack for this type of info. You can see in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e1f73aab8ca679a68a32bec6c0d72eb8a58d8788#actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb) that ActionController::Request began to inherit from Rack::Request. The referrer method is still available because it's coming from [Rack::Request](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L242) and will never actually go away unless Rack changes and removes it.